# Add error output to a script component SSIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssis

I have an SSIS data flow schema. In it I have an SSIS script component, with `try{} catch{}` inside. I would like to redirect all rows, that caught an exception, to different output than those that executed fine.

After googling I found about "use dispositions" option in the advanced options, but no explanation on how to use it with C# (there seemed to be a tutorial using VB). Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you not work out the C# from the VB?  They are essentially the same language, but with slightly different syntax.  All the important bits should be the same.

Comment: It's the same logic for adding an output buffer and columns but instead it's the Error branch. Then for sending data you'll use the same AddRow or assignment mechanism depending on whether this is async or sync